# jQuery: hasClass logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a dropdown menu and checking for classes etc. I'm having an issue where a condition is false, but it's being treated as true.

With the below code snippet, follow these instructions:

1. Click on `"item 1"`
2. Click on the plus icon above `"more"`
3. Click on `"item 1`" again

You'll notice that if you try to reopen the menu by clicking on `"item 1"` the menu does not open. Why? Those list items do NOT have a class of `"show"`... so those should open, irregardless of the second submenu, correct?

I'm not understanding what's wrong with my logic. I don't think this is a syntax error because there are no errors in console.

See below:

```js
$(function() {
  // main expansion element
  $(".expander").click(function() {
    var subShown = $("ul > li", this).hasClass("show");
    if (!subShown) {
      $(".indented", this).slideDown('100').addClass("show");
      $(".caret", this).addClass("reversedCaret");
    } else {
      $(".indented", this).slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
      $(".caret", this).removeClass("reversedCaret");
    }
  });

  // sub expansion element
  $(".sub-expander").click(function() {
    var subSelectText = $(".more-or-less").text();
    if (subSelectText != "More") {
      $(".indented--sub").slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
      $(".sub-caret").removeClass("reversedCaret");
      $(".more-or-less").text("More");
    } else {
      $(".indented--sub").slideDown('100').addClass("show");
      $(".sub-caret").addClass("reversedCaret");
      $(".more-or-less").text("Show Less");
    }
  });

  // stop propagation on the link element within .expander class
  $(".indented").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.expander:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-expander--indented {
  padding: 0 0 0 23px;
}

.sub-caret {
  margin-right: 75px;
}

.indented,
.indented--sub {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="expander">
  <span class="caret downCaret right visibleCaret">+</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">Item 1
      <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a>

      <ul class="sub-expander more" style="padding-top: 
0px;">
        <li class="indented--sub"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="moreLiAs">Chapter 5</a></li>
        <li class="indented--sub"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="moreLiAs">Chapter 6</a></li>
        <li class="indented--sub"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="moreLiAs">Chapter 7</a></li>
        <span class="sub-caret moreCaret visibleLessCaret right">+</span>
        <li class="more-or-less less sub-expander--
indented">More</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: works for me. Chrome v62.0.3202.89

Comment: weird ok....I'm on v61.0.3163.100 but idk why that would matter?

Comment: @zfrisch I just updated and it still doesn't work. What's your OS?

Comment: This happens because you add the `show` class to the `.indented--sub` elements, which is not removed when clicking on the `item-1`. Then the `$("ul > li", this).hasClass("show")` will always return `true`.

Comment: @kawnah Sorry it looks like I misunderstood your meaning. I was tapping on the top level `+` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/3z0zo2gn/

```
 } else {
  $(".indented", this).slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
  $(".caret", this).removeClass("reversedCaret");
  $(".indented--sub").slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
  $(".sub-caret").removeClass("reversedCaret");
  $(".more-or-less").text("More");
}
```

As stated in the above comment, you need to remove the show class from indented--sub when removing it from indented.

Comment: I see it's working but I'm not understanding why indented--sub impacted everything else? I'm only checking for the children of expander and that isn't a part of it, no?

Comment: This line: var subShown = $("ul > li", this).hasClass("show"); doesn't specify indented or indented--sub it simply specifies a list element. So ANY ul > li with a class of show will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't work because you didn't remove class `show` in li  with class `indented--sub`